# Installing packages into a library ignoring other libraries

Tags: r, install.packages

I currently have `testthat` installed on my machine. I want to install the package and all its dependencies (recursively) into a separate library. The problem is that when I try to do this using `install.packages("testthat", lib = "newdir")`, its dependencies, such as `xml2` are not installed along with it. How can I install a package and all its dependencies into a new library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

- use `install2.r` from [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) with its `-l` argument for the target library (and I do things like this all the time for reverse dependency checks
- maybe use a properly set/reset `.libPaths()` so that the current installation you are doing does not "see" the existing installations; worst case you make a copy of `install2.r` and set/reset `.libPaths()` there; you may need to experiment with `Rscript` vs `r` to launch it as `r` gets some values "baked in" during its compilation

Taken together it is basically what we do when we keep a separate R-devel on a box as well.

*Edit:* You can of course script this with `install2.r` -- it is just a wrapper to `install.packages()`.  But it happens to be setting the relevant arguments.

Comment: The second point was the one that I had trouble with. I tried modifying `.lib.loc` and promptly caused R to hang. I'm guessing I'd have to set some environmental variables visible to the script the achieve it?

Comment: Yes, `R_LIBS_USER` etc., see `help(Startup)`.  I usually just augment / prefix the path rather than wiping the existing one.

Comment: That was it. Really simple - I had `R_LIBS` set, but not `R_LIBS_USER`. Setting them both in a shell script calling my R script fixed the issue.